# What value should I set as Provider to connect to an Access Database in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, console-application, oledbconnection

I'm having trouble with code taken from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtE3kkQR7_w). I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft Access DB using a VB.NET Console Application. Here is the code:

```
Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
Dim dataFile As String = "C:\Users\[...]\Documents\JMdict.accdb"
Dim connString As String = provider & dataFile
Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection
myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
myConnection.Open()
```

The code fails on the last line, returning the error message:

```
'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."
```

It's clear that I need to input something different as the Provider value, but I don't know what needs to go there.

Comment: Is `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` installed in that machine? In which bitness version, x86 or x64? What is the bitness of your application (the two must match)?

Comment: My system is running Windows x64, but I confess I don't know what you mean by bitness. I didn't know that I needed to install additional software besides Visual Studio to connect to an Access DB

Comment: If you have MS Office installed, you should have `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` in a version that corresponds to the Office bitness (x86 or x64, 32bit or 64bit). Your app bitness must match the installed provider's bitness. See in Project → Properties → Compile, you should have selected `Target CPU: AnyCPU` and untick `Prefer 32-bit`. If you don't have Office installed, you need to download and install the provider, choosing the version that matches the bitness of your app. You can install both `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and `ACE.OLEDB.16.0`.

Comment: I do have Office installed, as I can access Access. Sorry, where is this menu? I can't see it on Access. I looked on Visual Studio, Project --> [ProjectName Properties] but couldn't see a Compile option.

Comment: When you right-click on the Project's name, a context menu shows up. Pick `Properties`. A new panel opens. On the left, you can select the `Compile` option. You didn't mention the installed Office version and bitness. Anyway, see that those match.

Comment: Brilliant, it worked. I downloaded the Microsoft Access Database Engine 64x bit from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255), and now I'm able to insert records through VB.NET. If you want to post an answer I can accept it.